# Prompting for a user input to be used on a Powershell command?

Tags: command-line, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to execute the code below and it is working:

```
PS C:\> Rename-Computer -NewName TEST -DomainCredential okadamanila\itservices
```

Given that hostname is given on the PS1 file - however, I would like to ask or prompt the user for input to substitute the hostname; I've tried using the code block below:

```
$hostname = read-host "Please enter your name"
Write-Host "YOUR PREFERRED HOSTNAME IS $hostname - INITIALIZING HOSTNAME CHANGE"
$credential = Get-Credential
PS C:\> Rename-Computer -NewName $name -DomainCredential $credential
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Where the input from the user would be the hostname that'll be used on the Rename-Computer function, it this possible?

EDIT:

The code block above seems to work, yet I'm encountering the issue below:

[ERROR BEING ENCOUNTERED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWZNV.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? If I do: `$var = read-host "Question: "` followed by `$var` I get inside $var what I entered at the question.

Comment: If you have a dedicated function to get the username ([`Get-UserName` would be the correct nomenclature, by the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx)), why would you put the `Read-Host` into a `param()`-block? I'd simply do `while($true){[string]$name = Read-Host "Enter a user-name"; if($name.Length -gt 0){break}else{Write-Out "You have to enter a name!"}}`

Comment: If you want to use the `param()`-block so you can call the function and the name-parameter so it does not prompt, then I'd suggest you test the `.Length` of `$name`, as `-name ""` is a valid string that does not contain any name. So `function Get-UserName(){param([string]$name); while($true){if($name.Length -eq 0){$name = Read-Host "enter a user-name"}else{Write-Out "You entered $name"; break}}` _Or is there an evident point I'm not seeing?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the prompt (`PS C:>`) before `Rename-Computer`.  You still need to change the variable name (from **myname** to **name**) that you have in `$myname = read-host "Please enter your name:"` so it reads `$name = read-host "Please enter your name:"` and matches what you have as a variable name in your call to the function `Rename-Computer -NewName $name -DomainCredential $credential`).